# Nth highest salary of an employee SQL when an Employee has multiple salaries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Calculate Nth highest salary for an employee when same employee has multiple salaries

```
CREATE TABLE Worker1 (
    WORKER_ID INT NOT NULL ,
    SALARY INT
);

INSERT INTO Worker1 
    ( WORKER_ID, SALARY) VALUES
        (001,100000),
        (001,80000),
        (003,300000),
        (002, 500000),
        (002,500000),
        (003,200000),
        (001, 75000),
        (002, 90000);
```

Table looks like this

```
WORKER_ID   SALARY
1            100000
1            80000
3            300000
2            500000
2            500000
3            200000
1            75000
2            90000
```

Let us say we need to calculate the 2nd highest salary of each employee. Similarly if someone asks to calculate 3rd highest, 4th highest, 5th highest salary and so on...

Comment: Why do you need this - one table for each worker?

Comment: Pls reopen that other question asks, 2nd highest paid employee, I am asking that the same person's 2nd highest salary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT WORKER_ID, 
       SALARY
FROM 
(
SELECT *, 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY WORKER_ID ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS SalaryRank
FROM Worker1
)
T 
WHERE SalaryRank = 2
```

In the event the employee has multiple entries for the same salary these will all be treated together for ranking purposes by `DENSE_RANK`. IF that is not what you want use `ROW_NUMBER` instead.